# Create two BelongsToMany, how do I delet only on in table?

Tags: laravel, relationship

So I've created two Models : 'Category' and 'Product',
within these tow I added function :

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongstoMany(Product::class);
}
```

and

```
 public function category()
{
    return $this->belongstoMany(Category::class);
}
```

and now I have in the Database :
category_id and product_id

And when I create an Relation like:
category_id 1 and product_id 2

How do I delete this, without deleting all enterys.

My function so far:

```
 $category = Category::where($request->categoryId);
$category->product()->detach();
```

But this acutally deletes or detaches all the enterys for the categoryId.

How do I do it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always browse [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching) first =)

```php
// IDs to be detached
$productIds = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
$category->product()->detach($productIds);

// Or single record
$category->product()->detach(2);
```